# Using Splinter to select from a dynamic menu

Tags: python, splinter

I am trying to run a splinter script in order to find a menu option in [this](http://databases.lovd.nl/shared/variants) webpage.

[image]

The menu's HTML looks like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="logo">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td align="left" style="background : url('gfx/tab_fill.png'); background-repeat : repeat-x;">
      ...
      <a href="variants">
          <img src="gfx/tab_variants_F.png" alt="View variants" id="tab_variants" width="58" height="25" align="left" class="">
      </a>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

<ul id="menu_tab_variants" class="jeegoocontext" style="display: none; left: 180px; top: 90px;">
  <li class="icon"><a href="/variants" class="">
      <span class="icon" style="background-image: url(gfx/menu_magnifying_glass.png);"></span>View all genomic variants</a></li>
  <li class="icon"><a href="/variants/in_gene" class="">
     <span class="icon" style="background-image: url(gfx/menu_magnifying_glass.png);"></span>View all variants affecting transcripts</a></li>
  <li class="icon"><a href="/submit" class="">
      <span class="icon" style="background-image: url(gfx/plus.png);"></span>Create a new data submission</a></li>
  ... 
</ul>
```

The script should hover over a menu header, show what is visible, and then hover out of it and show what elements are visible. But nothing appears visible.

```
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser('firefox', wait_time=10)    
browser.visit("http://databases.lovd.nl/shared/variants")

tab_variants = browser.find_link_by_href("variants")
print tab_variants

tab_variants.first.mouse_over()
print browser.find_link_by_partial_text(
    "View all genomic variants").first.visible
print browser.find_link_by_partial_text(
    "View all variants affecting transcripts").first.visible

tab_variants.mouse_out()
print browser.find_link_by_partial_text(
    "View all genomic variants").first.visible
print browser.find_link_by_partial_text(
    "View all variants affecting transcripts").first.visible
```

I get this output:

```
[<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x18c29d0>]
False
False
False
False
```

Am I using the mouse_over method as it is intended in `splinter` or is there something about this particular menu that `splinter` can't deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu is not yet visible at the time you are checking the `.visible` property. You can however wait for it by moving the mouse to the sub menu:

```
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser('firefox', wait_time=10)
browser.visit("http://databases.lovd.nl/shared/variants")

# move over the menu "Variant"
browser.find_by_id('tab_variants').mouse_over()
# move over the sub menu
browser.find_by_id('menu_tab_variants').mouse_over()

# print the menu items visibility
print browser.find_link_by_text("View all genomic variants").visible
print browser.find_link_by_text("View all variants affecting transcripts").visible

# move the mouse out of the sub menu
browser.find_by_id('menu_tab_variants').mouse_out()

# print the menu items visibility
print browser.find_link_by_text("View all genomic variants").visible
print browser.find_link_by_text("View all variants affecting transcripts").visible
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with that. It's so easy to miss a small but significant detail like that one.